Removing emacs broke my system
I uninstalled emacs using sudo apt remove emacs*.
As it was busy my screen suddenly turned black with just the top left flashing cursor.
After a restart, no desktop environment loads, I can only use the system with no desktop UI (such as eg ubuntu server)
Funny thing is, I could still open emacs haha.
Any way to know which packages got removed that shouldnt have?

Did you read the /var/log/apt/history.log to check which packages were removed during emacs removal?

This is more an apt problem than an emacs problem, so you probably will get more/better help at https://askubuntu.com

@gigiair Did not know that was a thing. I installed all the packages that was uninstalled in that command and it solved my problem. Thanks! I manually typed all the package names, is there a way to just do something like sudo apt reinstall history_item_1 or something like this?

@Joram I never head of such a command.
